# Settings certain data types into a database

Tags: java, jsp, cassandra, type-conversion

I'm having a lot of issues with resolving data types from my jsp form into my cassandra database.

In my 'registerUser' class, I had email set as a string for example, as I assumed it would be. So the user enters their email on the jsp form, which is then sent to the 'profiles' table. This process works for the login, password, forename and surname BUT it isn't working for Email, DOB and Gender, am I missing an obvious point working with these data types?

Email obviously has various types of chars in it so I set it as varchar in the database, but it's string in the jsp....I'm sure that's the issue.

DOB is a date selection box on the jsp form and gender is a select drop down box, not sure how to enter either of those. I've spent what seems like ages on this and would appreciate any help, even a nudge in the right direction would be great, I don't expect the answer given to me or anything!

EDIT- *****SOLVED*****

I am so sorry, thanks for all the input and help, I appreciate it but clearly I'm more exhausted than I thought. Been working on this constantly for days, building the database and website etc and there wasn't an error really. I had simply forgotten to create the column in my table, so there was nowhere for the data to be inserted! Again, sorry, and thanks for the help etc.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "it isn't working"?

Comment: **Email obviously has various types of chars**...  what do you  mean by various type of chars, you mean character encoding. because Java anyway has string as UTF-16, so not a big issue there.

Comment: Sorry I can't give an exact error description right now as I've popped out, I can give the email error though. When I tried entering an email address it said "invalid type, variable is a set and string was provided" basically.

Comment: Please make your problem clear... otherwise right solution can't be suggested.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding-
**Gender** is String only... Java datatype String and DB datatype VARCHAR should work in this case.
**DOB** can be set as Java Date object and then it can be mapped to DB Date or TimeStamp datatype.
**Email**, again this is Java String so can be mapped to DB VARCHAR in DB side.

Anyway my answer is based upon Oracle DB.

Cassandra Datatype-
`varchar` Represents uTF8 encoded string
`timestamp` Represents a timestamp
these both can be used in place of Oracle DB logic.

Comment: Cassandra is a very different beast

Comment: @ThomasStets so how does it change answer, Cassandra also has datatype similar to other DBs.